# providing input parameter for regex expression

Tags: r

I want to give input paramater for user weather he want to exclude sum of 0 from the output or not.

for example in my output df giving the sum of count of rows in in second row so i want to give input parameter  for user if he want to exclude 0 or not

Include_Error_only = TRUE then column having 0 will get excluded from the out put.

```
df <- data.frame(`External ID`=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                 "BB"=c("AMK","KAMl","HAJ","NHS","KUL","GAF","BGA","NHU","VGY","NHU"),
                 "CC"=c("TAMAN","GHUSI","KELVIN","DEREK","LOKU","MNDHUL","JASMIN","BINNY","BURTAM","DAVID"),
                 "DD"=c(62,41,37,41,32,74,52,75,59,36),
                 "EE"=c("CA","NY","GA","DE","MN","LA","GA","VA","TM","BA"),
                 "FF"=c("ENGLISH","FRENCH","ENGLISH","FRENCH","ENGLISH","ENGLISH","SPANISH","ENGLISH","SPANISH","RUSSIAN"),
                 "GG"=c(33,44,51,51,37,58,24,67,41,75),
                 `1A`=c("","D","","NA","","D","","","D",""),
                 `2B`=c("","A","","","A","A","A","A","",""),
                 `3C`=c("","","","","","","","","",""),
                 `4D`=c("","G","G","G","G","G","G","G","",""),
                 "Concatenate" = c("","DAG","G","NAG","AG","DAG","AG","AG","D",""))

df <- df %>% rename(`1. A`="X1A",`1. B`="X2B",`1. C`="X3C",`1. D`="X4D")

Include_Error_only = TRUE

orig_order = names(df)
summary_row12 = 
  df %>% 
  summarize(across(c(matches("^[0-9]"), Concatenate), ~sum(!is.na(.) &.!=" "  & . != "" & . != "NA")))

df <- bind_rows(mutate(summary_row12, across(everything(), as.character)), df)
df <- df[orig_order]
```

Currently this is the output

[image]

The output required is below (if the sum of rows in second row is 0 then i want to exclude that column)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be clear to do this with `if`/`else` -

```
Include_Error_only = TRUE

if(Include_Error_only) 
   df <- Filter(function(x) !all(x == 0 | x == '' | is.na(x)), df)
```

Comment: this is still showing 0 columns C 1. with Include_Error_only = TRUE and Include_Error_only = FALSE

Comment: if Include_Error_only = TRUE the this should exclude column "C 1." from output (the columns have sum of rows in second columns is 0)

Comment: @str_rst There is no 0 values in `df`. Can you show your expected output?

Comment: @str_rst See the updated answer. So if `Include_Error_only` is `TRUE` it will drop the 0 column.